# Update service configuration without restarting Express server

Tags: node.js, express, web-services, web, microservices

Currently, I met a problem when building a web server with Node Express. The problem is how to update some of the service configurations without restarting the service.

For example, the CDN site URL root or user upload file storage folder could be changed from time to time. Now, I put these service configuration into the object, which is required, when express server fires.

I know the `nodemon` could be used to monitor the file changes, and restarts itself.

Is there a better way to hot update these configuration variables without any outage?

BTW: in production deployment, it uses pm2, and the express server would run in multiple processes.